# Winston only writes to Console, does not successfully log anything to my log file

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, logging, winston

I am using NodeJS/React/Express/winston in conjunction. Here are the versions:

```
react & react-router-dom: 15.6.1

express: 4.15.3

node: 8.4.0

npm: 5.3.0

winston: 2.3.1

express-winston: 2.4.0
```

I instantiate my logger as such:

```
var logger = new (winston.Logger) ({
  transports: [
    new(winston.transports.File) ({
      filename: 'log.txt',
      handleExceptions: true,
      prettyPrint: true
    })
  ], exitOnError: false
});
```

I have created log.txt so the directory and file both exist.

At this point, I can go to my server and everything renders successfully as before.

If I add any calls to my logger, such as:

```
logger.info("Hello World!");
```

my application no longer renders, however I do not see any errors in the Console.

I have tried this as well with express-winston to log middleware requests which has the same outcome: logging works in the console for express-winson, but not when I want to write to an external file.

I just cannot seem to locate the source of this problem, it has absolutely baffled me. Please let me know if you see any red flags or have suggestions for how to debug this problem. Thank you very much for your time and help!

****** UPDATE ******
I have found that if I use:

```
try {
    logger.info("hello");
}
catch(e) { alert(e); }
```

I get this message: 
TypeError: fs.stat is not a function
I cannot find anything online that can fix this. Please advise

Comment: It might be a permission issue. Can you do a `chown youruser log.txt && chmod 700 log.txt` with the user running your node app.

Comment: @FrançoisP. - I ran both commands (although I believe the file was owned by me and had both read/write permissions set). Didn't change anything. This is a good thought, thanks for the suggestion. Anytime I try to use my logger (logger.error("some message")) my application breaks.

Comment: Can you add add `try {  logger.info("Hello World!"); } catch(e) { console.log(e); }` just after declaring your logger and the run your app and see if any error is logged.

Comment: So I wasn't getting anything back from the above code but i changed console.log(e) to alert(e), I get this error message: TypeError: fs.stat is not a function